# Language interpretation dilemma: How do I interpret this textual statement?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, formal-languages

How do I interpret this statement?

> Given a set *S* containing *n* real numbers and a real number *x*, there are two numbers in *S* whose sum is *x*.

It's not clear to me what we can assume here.  I'm not sure if *x* is necessarily in *S*.

My focus is on the assumption.  I guess there are two possible interpretations:

1)  $S = \{n_0, n_1, n_2, ...,n_n \}$ where $n \in \Re$, and $\exists x \in \Re$

or

2)  $S = \{n_0, n_1, n_2, ...,n_n, x \}$ where $n, x \in \Re$

Basically, is $x \in S$?

Comment: Not necessarily.  It is just some arbitrary real number.  It might be in S and it might not.

Comment: @PaulSundheim That's what I was thinking.  I think it would be *much* more clear if it said `Given a real number x and a set S containing n real numbers`.

Comment: Any chance you can upvote my answer as well? Haha

Comment: @BCLC Ack! I can't because my reputation isn't high enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If x was an element of S, it should be stated like "Given a set S containing n real numbers with a real number x being one of them" or "Given a set S containing n real numbers and a real number x in S"

Are you sure no further context is provided in the text?

Comment: I agree with you (and Paul).  There is no further context--this particular problem is from a computer science textbook so that may explain the lack of clarity (lol).

Comment: @heez :)) and oh yeah I found it "The Algorithm Design Manual
 By Steven S Skiena"